# My visual studio live server extension doesn't function normally

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio

So recently I started using the live server extension on Visual Studio. 
The issue that I am having with it is that whenever I update my HTML or Javascript file, my CSS styling will no longer show on the browser, and I have to go to the CSS file and save it for them to show.

I have included some screenshots to try to explain my issue:
[image]
So as you can see when I am on the app.css file, the correct styling is shown on the broswer.
[image]
However when I go to my javascript or HTML file and add something then all the styling is removed.

I will appreciate it so much if someone could help me with my issue.

When I checked the chrome developer console for any error I found the following error:

Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/app.css/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: When you open Chrome's developer console, do you see any error? If you look at the HTML source (Ctrl + U), do you see the CSS file included in the HTML? If you look in the network tab and reload, it the CSS file being loaded?

Comment: I checked the console and I get this error: Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/app.css/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: If you go to `http://127.0.0.1:5500/app.css` in your browser, what do you see?

Comment: It says: Cannot GET /app.css/

Comment: The only way I can reproduce the issue is if the `app.css` file is missing (i.e. not in the same directory as `index.html`). However, if it works "sometimes" for you, I guess that's not the issue you have... I don't know :(

Comment: Oh okay. Well, thanks for trying to help anyways :)

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure that whenever you open vs code, you select open folder and select your current project, and that your html,css, and js files all open then. When using live server(or at least on my machine), it will not work correctly unless the project is opened as a folder containing all of that projects files. I hope that makes sense and i hope that helps!